# How to create an index on a column in a table variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

Lets say I declare a table variable with some columns in it.

declare @MyContacts table (

//column definitions in it

);

Lets say I have a columnA in it, how can I index it in SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an index on a table variable can be done implicitly within the declaration of the table variable by defining a primary key and creating unique constraints. The primary key will represent a clustered index, while the unique constraint a non clustered index.

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE
(
    UserID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName varchar(50),
    UNIQUE (UserName)
)
```

For more info, chech [THIS](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/create-index-on-table-variable) article.

Comment: Can we have conditional unique constraint on table variable?

Answer (score 5):

**If you have a table big enough to need an index, don't do it in a table variable, do it in a temp table!**

Table variables have all kinds of limitations, including:

- No stats - the optimizer always assumes they have a single row
- No non-clustered indexes (besides for constraints)
- No visibility outside the immediate scope - a sub-proc can't access your table variable.
- Outside the scope of transactions - you can't `ROLLBACK` anything done to a table variable since it's not recorded in the transaction log

If you have something big enough to need an index, put it in a temp table instead.

Comment: +1 A unique constraint might be useful on a smallish data set, not for performance but for data protection, but in general I agree - if you need an index for performance reasons, you've likely chosen the wrong type of temporary object. Worth testing both, since that isn't universally true, but usually that's the way it works out.

Comment: Well I agree with your points, but in my case I wanted a table variable.

Comment: +1 We all concentrated on the direct question, you thought outside the box and gave valuable information for an alternative.

Comment: @DotNetUser a lot of folks want to drive without a seatbelt, too. So it's always useful to point out the problems with doing that.

Comment: For some scenarios, all these bullet points are *supporting* use of table variables...

Comment: @FactorMystic yes but not for large tables. If it's more than a hundred or so records IMO it should be in a #temp table.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @YourTempTable table
( 
    ID int not null primary key,
    Name nvarchar(255) null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it along with the column definition;

```
declare @MyContacts table (columnA int unique nonclustered ...)
```